# Make Javascript timer display 00 placeholder

Tags: javascript

```
var m=0;
var s=0;
var h=0;
var t;

function start(){
    document.getElementById('ms').innerHTML=m;
    document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML=s;
    document.getElementById('mh').innerHTML=h;
    s++;

    if(s==60){
        s=0;
        m++;
    }
    if(m==60){
        m=0;
        h++;
    }
    t= setTimeout("start()",20);
}

function stop(){
    clearTimeout(t);
}
```

When the counter is going incrememnting it does it displays a single digit. Not to sure how I can format the clock to resemble a digital clock i.e 00:00:00. Thanks

Comment: Add a string `"0"` when the value is less than 10.

Comment: Also, 1) don't hand a string to setTimeout but the function reference `start` 2) use set Interval 3) use 1000 ms as interval if you want to update it per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
var m = 0;
var s = 0;
var h = 0;
var t;

function start() {
  var z = '';
  z = (s < 10) ? '0' : '';
  document.getElementById('ms').innerHTML = z + s;
  s++;

  if (s == 60) {
    s = 0;
    z = (m < 10) ? '0' : '';
    document.getElementById('mm').innerHTML = z + m;
    m++;

    if (m == 60) {
      m = 0;
      z = (h < 10) ? '0' : '';
      document.getElementById('mh').innerHTML = z + h;
      h++;
    }
  }
  t = setTimeout(start, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(t);
}
```

```html
<span id="mh">00</span> : <span id="mm">00</span> : <span id="ms">00</span>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Please change `setTimeout("start()", 20)`, to `setTimeout(start, 20)`. Don't teach the eval version of `setTimeout`, it's awful practice.

Comment: @Oka Thank you for catching that. I had merely copied the asker's code.